# Huge loading indicator after changing team image

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, old-teams

I've decided to update our team with our shiny new logo, but in the process I noticed something particular:

> [image]

Instead of what I assume would be a loading indicator, huge black squares (that cover the left side of the page) appear after I click "Add picture"

Browser is Google Chrome 47.0.2526.111 (stable) on Windows 10

Comment: Yes. This is a known bug. Next one in our queue to look at actually.

Comment: it still exists even after 3 months, any update on this @Hynes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be pushed in the next deployment.